# Using 2 different Papyrus UMLstatemachines with the spring-statemachine project

Tags: eclipse, uml, state-machine, papyrus, spring-statemachine

**Link to the project on [github](https://github.com/joergi/uml-spring-state-machine/) for testing**
**The Payprus Files are [here](https://github.com/joergi/uml-spring-state-machine/tree/master/src/main/resources/papyrus)**

I'm trying to make a State-Machine with [Papyrus](https://eclipse.org/papyrus/). The State Machine should combine two single state-machines to one, as you can see in the first image: 
[image: State Machine Top]

the state machine 1 is defined in the 2nd picture and the state machine 2 is defined in the 3rd picture
[image: State Machine 1]
[image: State Machine 2]

I'm consuming the UML with my spring application (scroll down for code)

I tried this with a real simple single state machine (so only something like state machine 1 but with initial and final point) and it worked perfectly, the `System.out.println()` was writing the whole code.

But with this 2 state machines, the machine starts in the *TOP* at the *top_inital* point and goes then to *top_s1*. This was expected and working

Than i expected to go over the *topExitPoint1* to the *sm1EntryPoint* -> entering the *StateMachine1* -> than to *StateMachine2* -> back to *top* and so on.

But unfortunately the only state in my machine which was used has been the one in *top* -> the *top_s1* state.
The console log only shows me this:

```
2017-09-14 17:41:42.002  INFO 25414 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-09-14 17:41:42.008  INFO 25414 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
State change to top_s1
2017-09-14 17:41:42.070  INFO 25414 --- [           main] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : started org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor@4afd21c6
2017-09-14 17:41:42.070  INFO 25414 --- [           main] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : started top_s1 topFinalState top_r2_s1 top_s2 top_FinalState1 sm2_s1 sm2_s2 sm1_s2 sm1_s1  / top_s1 / uuid=e3a76fb9-5d3f-46b2-9c01-17d23eabedea / id=null
2017-09-14 17:41:42.071  INFO 25414 --- [           main] d.j.u.UmlSpringStateMachineApplication   : Started UmlSpringStateMachineApplication in 2.584 seconds (JVM running for 2.85)
2017-09-14 17:41:42.073  INFO 25414 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1e4a7dd4: startup date [Thu Sep 14 17:41:39 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-14 17:41:42.076  INFO 25414 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2017-09-14 17:41:42.077  INFO 25414 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : stopped org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor@4afd21c6
2017-09-14 17:41:42.078  INFO 25414 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : stopped top_s1 topFinalState top_r2_s1 top_s2 top_FinalState1 sm2_s1 sm2_s2 sm1_s2 sm1_s1  /  / uuid=e3a76fb9-5d3f-46b2-9c01-17d23eabedea / id=null
2017-09-14 17:41:42.078  INFO 25414 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-09-14 17:41:42.079  INFO 25414 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : destroy called
```

I tried so many things in Papyrus to change this behaviour, but nothing changes.
Would be cool, if someone can have a look to it, and maybe knows how to help.

Here is the Java Code: My `UmlSpringStateMachineApplication`

```
package de.joergi.umlspringstatemachine;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.statemachine.StateMachine;

@SpringBootApplication
public class UmlSpringStateMachineApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private StateMachine<String, String> stateMachine;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UmlSpringStateMachineApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        stateMachine.start();
    }   
}
```

and my `StateMachineConfig` looks like this:

```
package de.joergi.umlspringstatemachine;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.EnableStateMachine;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineModelConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.model.StateMachineModelFactory;
import org.springframework.statemachine.listener.StateMachineListener;
import org.springframework.statemachine.listener.StateMachineListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.statemachine.state.State;
import org.springframework.statemachine.uml.UmlStateMachineModelFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableStateMachine
public class StateMachineConfig extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<String, String> config) throws Exception {
        config.withConfiguration().autoStartup(false).listener(listener());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineModelConfigurer<String, String> model) throws Exception {
        model.
            withModel().factory(modelFactoryStateMachine());
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineModelFactory<String, String> modelFactoryStateMachine() {
        return new UmlStateMachineModelFactory("classpath:papyrus/new_test.uml");
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineListener<String, String> listener() {
        return new StateMachineListenerAdapter<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(State<String, String> from, State<String, String> to) {
                System.out.println("State change to " + to.getId());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If you want to see how the model explorer looks like:

[image: mode-explorer]

Comment: I suppose I need to try your project but I don't see how that model is valid as there is no initial state from where machine should start. Even on `top` state its right side region is missing initial state. Just this comment for now until I get to try it.

Comment: Hi @JanneValkealahti, thanks for the comment. there is one initial state in *TOP* on the *left* side. than it should (as far as I understood uml and state machines) go down to *StateMachine1* into the entry point and to *StateMachine2* and end up in *TOP right side* in the *TopFinalState* 

*StateMachine1* and *StateMachine2* should not be started alone - just going into the EntryPoint and leaving through Exit Points.

Is there than an Initial Point needed for *StateMachine1* and *StateMachine2* ?

Comment: I have to ask that how did you manage to add those other state machine outside of top machine? I can now see this when I opened this is papyrus but I can't create anything outside of top.

Comment: in model explorer: right click on "New Test" --> new Diagram -> new State Machine.
Than I klicked on the model TOP and pulled the new state machine into the Top. I hope this explains what I mean @JanneValkealahti

Comment: wow, how about that, didn't know you can pull those machines from model explorer into a model graph itself. I'm not sure what kind of model that represents or is it even valid. Usually additional machines are used as a sub-machine reference in a state. I need to read uml specs again if there's some notes what this mean.

Comment: maybe this is not correct, but that's how I did it....

maybe sub-machines are more correct?  not sure how to do this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i fixed this, with building two separate State-Machines together in one project and connecting them 
https://github.com/joergi/uml-spring-state-machine/  see the new push to master